# Is it possible to use Saxon-JS to convert a JSON file to a different JSON file without transiting through XML?

Tags: node.js, json, xslt, saxon-js

I'm doing research to solve a transformation problem that is fundamentally based entirely in JSON, and while imperative code-based solutions are possible, there is appeal in using an established technology like XSLT and leveraging its many features rather than trying to in-house everything from scratch. I'm fairly inexperienced with XSLT but I would love for this effort to provide a reason to learn it.

I've read that JSON is included in XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 specs, and that Saxon-JS supports these, and furthermore that Saxon-JS has a node.js version. This has me very interested, but I haven't found much in the way of tutorials that provide instruction about how to transform JSON into other JSON; instead the focus appears to be on transforming JSON into XML.

This question is kind of broad and so I'd be happy to know just whether this is possible, and maybe where to look to start learning, but stackoverflow likes examples. With that in mind, what would a stylesheet look like that converts the first of these JSON documents to the second?

Source:

```
{
    "contents" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "color": "blue",
            "hexcode": "#0000FF"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "color": "green",
            "hexcode": "#00FF00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "color": "red",
            "hexcode": "#FF0000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "contents1",
        "color": {
            "name": "blue",
            "hexcode": "#0000FF"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "contents2",
        "color": {
            "name": "green",
            "hexcode": "#00FF00"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "contents3",
        "color": {
            "name": "red",
            "hexcode": "#FF0000"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, as Martin shows. However, XSLT still has a little way to go before JSON-to-JSON transforms work as smoothly as XML-to-XML. The main limitations in my experience are:

(a) it isn't as easy to write match patterns for `xsl:template` that match "nodes" in a JSON tree

(b) because there's no parent or ancestor axis for JSON, the processing of a particular "node" in the JSON tree has no access to the context in which it appears, which means it's necessary to pass that context down using template parameters (tunnel parameters come in very handy for this.)

In your example, the input data is completely flat, so these problems don't show up.

Comment: This is great information, thank you! Given that my eventual output is JSON, if I weren't using JSON-to-JSON directly, would the approach be to perform a structural JSON-to-XML transform first, availing me of parent/ancestor axes, and then finishing it with a type of identity transform using `output method="json"` perhaps?

Comment: @bwerks, XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 functions `json-to-xml` and `xml-to-json` exists so the structure would be `<xsl:param name="json-input-uri"/><xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"><xsl:variable name="transformed-xml-of-json-input"><xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text($json-input-uri))"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-to-xml-transformed, map { 'indent' : true()})"/></xsl:template>` plus templates that perform the transformation you want/need on the result the `json-to-xml` call gives (i.e. the XML representation of JSON defined in XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0).

Comment: @bwerks, the representation of JSON as XML, as produced by `json-to-xml` and consumed by `xml-to-json`, is shown in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#json-to-xml-mapping.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="array{ ?contents?*!map { 'id' : 'contents' || ?id, 'color' : map { 'name' : ?color, 'hexcode' : ?hexcode } } }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

e.g. [at the Saxon-JS fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28*%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22array%7B%20%3Fcontents%3F*%21map%20%7B%20%27id%27%20%3A%20%27contents%27%20%7C%7C%20%3Fid%2C%20%27color%27%20%3A%20map%20%7B%20%27name%27%20%3A%20%3Fcolor%2C%20%27hexcode%27%20%3A%20%3Fhexcode%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22contents%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%230000FF%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22green%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%2300FF00%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%23FF0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON) then the JSON is parsed into an XPath 3.1 map and an XPath 3.1 array is constructed that is serialized back as JSON.

For the Node.js `xslt3` command line tool you can use `-json:my-input.json` I think instead of the `s:my-source.xml` you would use to transform XML. I think that `-json` option is only in Saxon-JS 2.3 so make sure you use the latest version.

For a more general treatment and a debate of advantages and shortcoming of working only on the XDM representation of maps/arrays of JSON instead of using the XML representation you might get from `json-to-xml` see https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf, https://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2017/11/transforming-json.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGehtNUrg60.

For the syntax to query XPath 3.1 maps and arrays see https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31 or the XPath 3.1 spec or any other tutorial on XPath 3.1 arrays/maps.

Comment: I'm using Saxon-JS 2.3 and you're right, when using xslt3 the doc is passed with -json. I tested out the stylesheet you posted and it works exactly as described. This is a great starting point, thank you for the example and the links!